# show auth popup in spotify preview api

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to migrate a spotify app into the new preview API. 
Using the old framework I could get access to auth module and show an oauth popup using showAuthenticationDialog method.

However, I can't find the equivalent in the preview API.

Would appreciate any help

Thx,
Adaf

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no equivalent to the auth module in the [Preview API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/preview/). This API is still under development, so changes will be made until it is finally released.

Comment: hi, I am fecing the same problem please help me if u find any solution on it